# How QUIC protocol is run on redundant servers?

Tags: server, chromium

Lately, I am learning the QUIC protocol to confirm whether QUIC protocol is effective to our redundant server.

When QUIC client try to connect the server at first, as far as I know, client can get the server's config after 'SHLO' required 1-RTT.

If the connected server is down, client try to connect another server(in redundant servers).

In this case, client should get another server's config required 1-RTT again?

Any method to connecting another server in 0-RTT is exist?

Thanks.